# Ethernet cable unplugged on Ubuntu 20.10 on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: networking, ethernet, raspberrypi

On a Rasberry Pi 4 I have Ubuntu 20.10 and I don't manage to connect it to the newtwork via  ethernet cable. It says 'cable unplugged' on the Settings and none of what I tried on the command line works.
I've tried plugging the cable before and after boot.
There are not LED indicating the cable is plugged in, I don't know if this is normal.
`sudo ifconfig eth0 up` didn't help 
in `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` there is always a '0'
in `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstat` I see 'down'

**ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:da:71:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3821  bytes 378769 (378.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3821  bytes 378769 (378.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**nmcli device status**

```
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
eth0           ethernet  unavailable  --         
wlan0          wifi      unavailable  --         
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  unavailable  --         
lo             loopback  unmanaged    --
```

**nmcli device show eth0**

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         DC:A6:32:DA:71:45
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
```

**cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are not LED indicating the cable is plugged in, I don't know if this is normal.

It's not. Probably your cable or ethernet port in either end is broken. Try with a different cable, and verify that connection to a different computer works.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I tried that port and cable with a laptop PC, it all works. I've also now tried just to be sure with other cables.

Answer (score 0):

So this was not an Ubuntu question. Sorry for having posted it here.
This was a Raspberry question and the answer is that the Pi 4 is strict regarding the cable. It has to be a Gigabit one (all the way from the router to the Pi). My test with the laptop PC was not 100% relevant or sufficient. 
I've now plugged the Raspberry with a cat.5e Gigabit cable directly to the (Swisscom - I live in Switzerland) router and it works just fine. LEDs turn on, ifconfig displays the eth0 connection (ip etc), /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier has '1'. And for the records, same behavior with Raspberry Pi OS and Ubuntu.